# IIS Default Web Site locking down virtual directories

Tags: security, iis, virtual-directory

I have a Web Site in IIS 6.0 that hosts several virtual directories.  Some of the virtual directories in the Web Site need to be served out to the internet, so there is a public DNS entry for the Web Site as a whole.  Other virutal directories should not be served to the internet, but they get exposed by default through the public DNS host.

Is it possible to "lock down" certain virtual directories and not others within a single Web Site?  Or would you need to create a different Web Site to separate the virtual directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using any kind of Url Rewriting  filter, you could use it to hide the directories you want.
Alternatively you can change the permissions on those directories to disallow access ..

You could also restrict access to those directories from IPs other than your internal network addresses..

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "locking down" if all you want to do is lock a vdir to only allow certain IP addresses or subnets, then you can do this on any level of the web site - even a page if you want! You can also assoc a site with a network card, and only feed traffic from that network card.

Finally, if you want to get REALLY techy, you could always IPSec to limit traffic from certain IP addresses.